# Karate UI & Selenium standalone server input commands not working

Tags: selenium, karate

I am running selenium-standalone server locally and trying to run this example feature against it.

```
Scenario: try to login to github and then do a google search
Given driver 'https://github.com/login'
And input('#login_field', 'dummy')
And input('#password', 'world')
When submit().click("input[name=commit]")
Then match html('#js-flash-container') contains 'Incorrect username or password.'

Given driver 'https://google.com'
And input("input[name=q]", 'karate dsl')
When submit().click("input[name=btnI]")
Then waitForUrl('https://github.com/intuit/karate')
```

I have configured my driver as such

```
* configure driver = { type: 'chromedriver', start: false, webDriverUrl: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub' }
```

Chromedriver is running:

```
ChromeDriver 2.46.628411 on port 9515
```

The chrome browser displays and navigates to Google.  The *input* command/method **attempts** to write the login id and password and clicks the Commit button.  The error message expected by the test does display so the test passes.

The issue is *input* command/method **attempts** while running in this configuration.  It does not input dummy or world into the appropriate fields they are just left empty.

If I run the feature with this driver configuration `* configure driver = { type: 'chrome', showDriverLog: true }` it works just fine.

I am not very familiar with this configuration and just starting to use Karate UI but we do use selenium-standalone server and chromedriver with other projects and do not experience this issue.

I did search for a solution but wasn't able to find anything useful.

Has anyone else run into this issue before and if so how did you resolve it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Very well can be an old version of Selenium server. Just checked and this works with Chrome / ChromeDriver 83

It would help if you can follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/examples/ui-test